# Regular expression to accept multiple expressions

Tags: java, regex

I have this regular expression:

```
\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}-\\d{2} \\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}.*
```

It matches Strings like:

"2014-02-16-13 53.22.115621"

I want it to match also string like this:

"2014-02-16-13.53.22.115621"

Comment: If you are parsing date time, using DateTimeFormatter.

Comment: The given regular expression doesn't match that input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean something like this? (Hope I did not miss another difference.)

```
\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}[ .]\d{2}:\d{2}.*
```

I think there was some problems with your initial regex.

For completeness here it is in escaped form:

```
"\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}[ .]\\d{2}:\\d{2}.*"
```